# Прозрачность в ие7,8 для плагина лайтбокс

Tags: jquery, html, css

При подключении к странице этого плагина [лайтбокса](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) в ие7 и ие8 страница не затемняется, а становится полностью черной и непрозрачной. Для дива, который натягивается на страницу, заданы свойства

```
#lightboxOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: black;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=85);
  opacity: 0.85;
  display: none;
}
```

при этом для ие вроде бы должно срабатывать свойство filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=85); но, получается, оно не срабатывает. За счет чего можно задать полупрозрачное затемнение в ие7,8 ?

Comment: Нарисуйте полупрозрачный gif и сделайте его фоном.

Comment: спасибо, можно поробовать